# Authentication fails though the password is correct

Tags: rhel, pam, sssd

I have a linux 7.7 machine which is integrated to Windows Active Directory. Also I have a local user "appuser" in the server for managing the application. While I switch to appuser, I am getting "su - Authentication Failure" Error. And in the /var/log/secure I get the below message.

su: pam_sss(su-l:auth): received for user appuser: 10 (User not known to the underlying authentication module)

How can I fix this?

Comment: There is no such thing (yet) as 'linux 7.7'. The developers are still working at version 5.8. You probably mean 'version 7.7 of some distribution'. Which distribution is it ?

Comment: Seeing as the tag “rhel” is on the question, it’s probably RHEL 7.7 (so, a system that hasn’t got all the latest software updates, so it could be certificate related)

Comment: Yes it is RedHat Linux. I missed to add that.